# jest and mongoose - jest has detected opened handles

Tags: mongoose, jestjs

So I'm using `jest` to test my node.js application and the tests finish fine but I'm getting a message from jest about open handles. Any insights?

> > jest --detectOpenHandles
>
> PASS  src/libs/user/**tests**/user_model_test.js  PASS 
>   src/**tests**/app_test.js  PASS 
>   src/libs/user/**tests**/user_service_test.js
>
> Test Suites: 3 passed, 3 total Tests:       14 passed, 14 total
>   Snapshots:   0 total Time:        7.209s Ran all test suites.
>
> Jest has detected the following 4 open handles potentially keeping
>   Jest from exiting:
>
> ●  PROMISE
>
> ```
>   2 | // we use a test database for testing
>   3 | var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/my_db_conn';
> > 4 | mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
>     |          ^
>   5 | const User = require('../user_model');
>   6 |
>   7 | describe("User model test", () => {
>
>   at NativeConnection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.openUri (node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:424:19)
>   at Mongoose.Object.<anonymous>.Mongoose.connect (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:208:15)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/libs/user/__tests__/user_model_test.js:4:10)
> ```
>
> ●  PROMISE
>
> ```
>    8 | });
>    9 |
> > 10 | module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
>      |                           ^
>
>   at Function.init (node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:962:16)
>   at Mongoose.Object.<anonymous>.Mongoose.model (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:392:11)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/libs/user/user_model.js:10:27)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/libs/user/__tests__/user_model_test.js:5:14)
> ```
>
> ●  PROMISE
>
> ```
>    8 | });
>    9 |
> > 10 | module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
>      |                           ^
>
>   at Function.init (node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:962:16)
>   at Mongoose.Object.<anonymous>.Mongoose.model (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:392:11)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/libs/user/user_model.js:10:27)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/libs/user/index.js:1:41)
> ```
>
> ●  PROMISE
>
> ```
>   3 | var mongoose = require('mongoose');
>   4 | var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/my_db_conn';
> > 5 | mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
>     |          ^
>   6 |
>   7 | describe('App test', () => {
>   8 |     it('has a module', () => {
>
>   at NativeConnection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.openUri (node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:424:19)
>   at Mongoose.Object.<anonymous>.Mongoose.connect (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:208:15)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/app_test.js:5:10)
> ```

Answer (score 10):

after many hours of searching for a solution on SO and github issues, I came across this github thread https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/520 with multiple solutions offered. what was finally working for me was implementing a global-teardown-file in my root directory like so:

```
// test-teardown-globals.js
module.exports = () => {
  process.exit(0);
};
```

and also by adjusting my jest.config.js slightly

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/test-teardown-globals.js',
};
```

update: please also note @SimonSimCity 's comment, this solution comes with some tradeoffs. Consider using Özgür Atmaca's answer by disconnecting the mongoose connection instead.

Comment: Miraculous! Your answer has saved me from several hours of frantic debugging and searching for fixes up to page 3 of Google. Works!!

Comment: glad i was able to do that for you :D

Comment: **CAUTION:** By using this, your process will always have `0` as return code, even when having failing tests! Usually the command would return `1` on error.  Background: Most systems rely on the return code to determine if a command ran successfully.

Comment: thanks for the headsup! so this solution is only viable for local tests on my computer but not for tests running on a pipeline on a server for instance? @SimonSimCity

Comment: @Fiehra exactly. I would also refrain from using it locally. I learned it the hard way and needed a tremendous amount of time to again gain trust in the CI pipelines and process after this incident...

Comment: Don't choose this solution, if you have open handle you should close them (databases connection like redis/mongo, websockets etc). It will far cleaner that exiting the process.

Answer (score 8):

It seems your mongoose connection remains open after your test, try one of the following:

1. close server instance after test.

   ```
   const server = require('./app'); //server instance    
   server.close(); //put in afterAll or afterEach depending on your test
   ```
2. close your database connection after all your test.

   ```
   afterAll(()=>{ mongoose.connection.close();});
   ```
3. wrap your mongoose connection with async/await.

   ```
   async function(){
      await mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
   };
   ```

try one or a combination.
These are my solutions since I can't really see your code.

Comment: this causes `causes Matcher error` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68340573/closing-mongoose-connection-in-a-jest-test-causes-matcher-error @kenneth

Comment: I'm still getting the openHandles error for mongoose.connect after adding `mongoose.connection.close()`

Comment: @pavittarx make sure you also did step 3 above. async/await on the connection piece.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me in 2022, error still persists

Answer (score 4):

I was having same issue with Mongoose and managed to fix it like this

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
  await mongoose.disconnect();
  await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URL, MONGODB_OPTIONS);
});
```

Most "solutions" I found was around timers and I am not a fan of fixing things with timers, so above workaround feels more natural to me, hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe it is also good to check current state before disconnecting. `mongoose.connection.readyState`

Comment: I have no idea how this works but it does work

Answer (score 3):

It's related to `model.init` function which returns promise. Quick fix will be to pass `skipInit` flag while creating the model like this:

`const User = mongoose.model("users", userSchema, "users", true)`

`skipInit` is the fourth parameter in this function

But in this case it will not initialize indexes for your model, so it's better to set this flag according to the `process.env.NODE_ENV`

`const skipInit = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test"
const User = mongoose.model("users", userSchema, "users", skipInit)`

Comment: I have just started with almost empty project without any model and having same error. So this at least not works for me.

Comment: @Alex I used your answer and it works - it prevents jest complaining about open promises. However, I'm not sure if it has other issues. In my live database, it correctly complains about duplicate email as it is a unique field. In my test database through mockgoose, it doesn't error. I can only assume because of setting the skipInit = false, but I am continuing to investigate