# mongoose.connect leaves open handles after jest test

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jestjs

How to get rid of the openHandles left by `mongoose.connect` in jest test

```js
const { startTestDB } = require("../conn");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const request = require("supertest");
const faker = require("faker");
const app = require("../app");
const fs = require("fs");

describe("test1: ", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    startTestDB()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to db.");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    mongoose
      .disconnect()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('db connection is closed');
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  });

  it("Should save a new user", async () =>
    request(app)
      .post("/save")
      .send({
        name: faker.internet.userName(),
        email: faker.internet.email()
      })
      .expect(201));
});
```

This is an example code that has the same problem, when I run `npx jest --detectOpenHandles` I find one at `mongoose.connect`, as per my knowledge open handles occur because of async operations that didn't finish before tests, but I clearly close the connection in `afterAll`.

The Error Message I got:

```
  ●  TLSWRAP

       9 |
      10 | module.exports.startTestDB = () =>
    > 11 |   mongoose.connect(
         |            ^
      12 |     `mongodb+srv://${mongodb.user}:${mongodb.password}@${mongodb.host}/${mongodb.db}-test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
      13 |     {
      14 |       useNewUrlParser: true,

      at parseSrvConnectionString (node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:67:7)
      at parseConnectionString (node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:597:12)
      at connect (node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:282:3)
      at node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:260:5
      at maybePromise (node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:692:3)
      at MongoClient.Object.<anonymous>.MongoClient.connect (node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:256:10)
      at node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:835:12
      at NativeConnection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.openUri (node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:832:19)
      at node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:351:10
      at node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
      at promiseOrCallback (node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
      at Mongoose.Object.<anonymous>.Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
      at Mongoose.connect (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:350:20)
      at startTestDB (conn.js:11:12)
      at tests/s.test.js:10:5
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:387:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:408:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:261:3)
```

Comment: did you find a solution? i have tried closing the connection like you and also did some changes to code as recommended in other answers but handles are still open for me

Comment: That may depend on a range of factors. I use `mongoose.connect()` in `beforeAll()` and `mongoose.disconnect()` in `afterAll()` and that does the trick at the moment in my case. I don't see open handles reported by Jest.

Answer (score 5):

I am reposting my answer from this question [jest and mongoose - jest has detected opened handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687592/jest-and-mongoose-jest-has-detected-opened-handles/71143769#71143769) as this was my solution for the problem.

closing the connection as many others have proposed did not work for me.

after many hours of searching for a solution on SO and github issues, I came across this github thread https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/520 with multiple solutions offered. what was finally working for me was implementing a global-teardown-file in my root directory like so:

```
// test-teardown-globals.js
module.exports = () => {
  process.exit(0);
};
```

and also by adjusting my jest.config.js slightly

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/test-teardown-globals.js',
};
```

UPDATE: although this works this solution is only viable for developing and running tests locally. I also prefer Özgür Atmaca's solution by disconnecting before reconnecting in the beforeAll block

Answer (score 3):

I am too reposting my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73673449/4012944

Mongoose web site clearly does not recommend using Jest with Mongoose apps and does not recommend timers or global setups/teardowns.

Such workaround feels more natural to me.

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
  await mongoose.disconnect();
  await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URL, MONGODB_OPTIONS);
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I just added `await mongoose.disconnect()` in `afterAll()` and that did the trick for me. I don't see open handles reported by Jest.